# Using reflection to find constructors that have interface parameters

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.0

I am loading up all assemblies in my app domain and then trying to find those of a certain base type and all also whose constructors have a interface as a constructor argument.  I've got the below code but can't work out how you tell it to find interface parameters.

```
var assembliesWithPluginBaseInThem = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(x=>x.GetTypes().Where(y=>y.BaseType== typeof(PluginBase) &&
     y.GetConstructor(new Type[]{typeof(interface)})
```

Comment: You're not trying to build yet another IoC container are you? ;)

Comment: Nope just trying to limit the assemblies I pass into my IOC

Comment: Which IoC container are you using?

Comment: I don't know TinyIOC but usually containers have features to help you register types that have specific ancestors or implement specific interfaces. (I use Autofac, which builder has a RegisterAssemblyTypes for that purpose)

Comment: Yup I know that method in Autofac. The issue is I 58 assemblies in my AppDomain and only about 3 that have classes in them that inherit PluginBase. Some of them also might not have any DI in them at present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var assembliesWithPluginBaseInThem = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(x =>
        x.GetTypes().Any(y =>
            typeof(PluginBase).IsAssignableFrom(y) &&
            y.GetConstructors().Any(z =>
                z.GetParameters().Count() == 1 && // or maybe you don't want exactly 1 param?
                z.GetParameters().All(a => a.ParameterType.IsInterface)
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: This was general idea, thought you could at least fill in the blanks, but here it is.

Comment: This seems to be doing an OR somehow as its returning all PluginBase even if they don't have a interface constructor argument

Comment: Should be something like this
`var typeNames = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .Where(x =>
        typeof(PluginBase).IsAssignableFrom(x) &&
        x.GetConstructors().Any(y =>
            y.GetParameters().Count() == 1 &&
            y.GetParameters().All(z => z.ParameterType.IsInterface)
        )
    )
    .Select(x => x.FullName);`

Comment: Sorry, mistake was I placed `Form` instead of `PluginBase` in code since you insisted code must compile :)

Comment: I've taken the Count() == 1 out and it still seems to be doing an OR as mentioned above so I replaced the All call to Any and it seems to work. Not sure why!

Answer (score 3):

```
var types =
    from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from t in a.GetTypes()
    where t.GetConstructors()
                 .Any(c => c.GetParameters()
                              .Any(p => p.ParameterType.IsInterface))
    select t;
```

Answer (score 1):

to check is a class in a subclass of a certain type I would suggest you to use

```
yourClass.IsSubclassOf(typeof(parentClass))
```

so it should look like the below:

```
var assembliesWithPluginBaseInThem = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(x=>x.GetTypes().Where(y=>y.IsSubclassOf(typeof(PluginBase)) &&
     y.GetConstructor.Any(c => c.GetParameters()
                              .Any(p => p.ParameterType.IsInterface)
```

Comment: PluginBase is abstract if that makes a difference